# Methods of visualization_msgs/MarkerArray

Tags: interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Where can I find a complete documentation of visualization_msgs/MarkerArray? I m interested in methods of visualization_msgs/MarkerArray.
2. Also as it is an array so I assume that it will contain only 1 type of Marker, right?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374842/methods-of-visualization_msgs/markerarray./) by [SurajJadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/71239/surajjadhav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2021-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. You can find the documentation here: http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/MarkerArray.html
   As you can see, it is just an array of http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/Marker.html
2. They can be of different type, because the different types all use the same class, as you can see from the previous link.

You can also find more info here https://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker and here https://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers:%20Basic%20Shapes

---

Originally posted by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) with karma: 862 on 2021-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SurajJadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/71239/surajjadhav/) on 2021-04-09**:
Thanks ct2034,
Thanks for your reply.

1. The sources you shared does not talk about any methods of visualization_msgs/MarkerArray.
2. So, it id clear that the array can contain any type marker.

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2021-04-09**:
That's probably because they do not have methods. These message types, as all ROS message types, are only containers for data. So you will have to assign values to them directly and then publish them. For example `marker.pose.position.x = 99`

**Comment by [SurajJadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/71239/surajjadhav/) on 2021-04-09**:
Will you take a look at line #41 of code given [link text]. (http://docs.ros.org/en/fuerte/api/rviz/html/marker__array__test_8py_source.html)
The code uses append() method. There are many such examples.

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2021-04-09**:
Okay, sorry. Anything that is defined as an array in the msg file (like `Marker[] markers` here) will be converted to a `std::vector<Marker>` in c++ (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector for their methods).
There are some other specialities about messages that you can find here: http://wiki.ros.org/action/show/msg?action=show#Fields

**Comment by [SurajJadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/71239/surajjadhav/) on 2021-04-14**:
Thanks @ct2034, this is what I needed. It is very useful information and is not provided in the official documentation.

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2021-04-14**:
cool, happy that it helped. Can you please click the checkbox next to the answer then.